# Compelling but simple combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I'm a Software Engineer with no formal education in advanced math, especially not combinatorics. I'm sorry if this is too easy for you, but I've stumbled upon a simple problem that turned out to be quite troublesome.

Let's say we have a string of $100$ bits. If we ask how many unique combinations are there so there's the same amount of zeroes and ones - it's easy: $2^{100}$. Where I got into trouble is the following snag - how many unique combinations are there if the max amount of the same digit in a row is $n$?

For example, if $n$ is $6$:

`10000001... this combination is valid`

`100000001... this combination is not`

Once again, I'm sorry if this is too simple for you - but I've even failed big in searching for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your answer for the number of combinations with the same number of $1$s and $0$s is wrong.... Replace $100$ with $2$ and you'll see why.

Comment: When $n=2$ you get the Fibonacci numbers. Then https://oeis.org/A000073 ... etc ...

Comment: In general I think this $2$ times the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-(x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)}$. (The factor of $2$ that Donald Splutterwit omits comes from the choice of whether the first bit is $1$ or $0$; the rest counts the number of ways to write $100$ as the sum of integers between $1$ and $n$ inclusive.)

Comment: I think it would be much easier to think about the proportion of strings that are not valid, and use that result to answer your question

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit It can't be the Fibonacci numbers for $n=2$, since in that case the sequence begins with $2,4,\cdots$.

Comment: @jjagmath Ooops ... When I said $n=2$, I mean't $n=1$.

Comment: To clarify your question:  Do you want the number of strings using no more than $n$ consecutive bits of either type, also subject to the constraint that the string should use exactly $50$ of each bit?  Or is the consecutive-bit limitation the only constraint on your string?  By the way, the number of strings using exactly $50$ of each bit is $\binom{100}{50} \lt 2^{100}$.  This is the number of $50$-subsets of a $100$-set.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit For $n=1$ the sequence is $2,2,2,\cdots$.

Comment: @jjagmath It's Fibonacci _related_ — specifically, it's $2F_n$ for $n\geq 1$. (e.g., for $n=3$ the strings are `001`, `011`, `010`, and the inverse of each of these). As soon as we choose a starting bit it becomes isomorphic to the problem of covering a $n\times 1$ strip with $1\times 1$ squares and $2\times 1$ dominos; since the inverse of any such sequence (for arbitrary lengths) is also a (different) valid sequence, it makes sense (to me) to divide by $2$ and consider all the sequences as starting with `0`.

Comment: Oh, I was afraid I won't be precise enough in clarifying my question.

Let's try with a smaller set of numbers so it's easier for me to precisely determine the variables. I also realized I got the wrong solution for the "easy" problem as well. 

Variables:
n - number of digits in a string (always even, as number of zeroes and ones in a string must be the same)
k - the max amount of the same digit in a row
x - total number of valid combinations

Comment: If n = 4 and k = 2, we have 6 possible combinations (all). But if k = 1, we have only 2 valid combinations - [1010] and [0101]... [1001] for example is not a valid combination as there are 2 zeroes in the row (>k).

Comment: Is there any "formula" that could work on any pair of n and k?

Comment: To clarify further, if n = 6 and k = 3, we have all 20 possible combinations as valid. But if k = 2, we have 12 valid combinations as combinations such as [111000] and [001110] aren't valid (there're three 1 in them).

Comment: (It is unclear whether $k$ in a row is the maximum allowed or one more than the maximum allowed, in what follows, I take it as the maximum.) There will be a recursion that works for any $n$ and $k$.  Consider $T_k(a,b)=\sum\limits _{c=1}^k T_k(b,a-c)$ when $a>0$, starting with $T_k(0,0)=1$, $T_k(0,b)=0$ when $b >0$, and $T_k(a,b)=0$  when $a<0$ or $b<0$.  Then you want $2T_k(n,n)$

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to implement what you wrote. I don't get what are a,b,c, and k variables and how to use them.

Is there any exact formula on how to get it?

For example, If there's no [k] in the problem, the total number of combinations is n! / ((n/2)! * (n/2)!). If n = 6, the total number of combinations is 6! / (3! * 3!) = 20. But if k = 2, total number of combinations is 12. I can't figure out how to modify this formula n! / ((n/2)! * (n/2)!) to work with [k]?

Comment: @TheodoreWilliams: How are you breaking up the string into rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unlikely to be a closed form (see the OEIS references later) though I suspect that for any given $k$ there will be an asymptotic approximation something like $w \frac{v^n}{\sqrt{n}}$  for some constants $w$ and $v$.

Slightly adjusting the notation, let's suppose we want to know how many ways we can arrange $n$ bits of one type and $n$ bits of another with no consecutive runs of length strictly greater than $k$ of a single type, and starting with either type of bit.   So in the example $n=50$ and $k=6$.

As a step towards this, first consider how many ways we can arrange $a$ bits of one type and $b$ bits of another with no consecutive runs of length strictly greater than $k$ of a single type, starting with the first type of bit, and call this number $T_k(a,b)$.  Clearly we can start with the first type and have any number of them from $1$ through to $k$, at which point we reverse the problem and need to complete the sequence next using the other type of bit with the remaining bits. We will then have  $$T_k(a,b)=\sum\limits _{c=1}^k T_k(b,a-c)$$  starting with $T_k(0,0)=1$, $T_k(0,b)=0$ when $b>0$, and $T_k(a,b)=0$ when $a<0$ or $b<0$.

When we want the answer to the original question, we can start with either type of bit, and have equal numbers of each type, so want $2\, T_k(n,n)$.

The recursion needed to get the table is not particularly difficult to program, for example in R:

```
up <- function(x, k){ x + k }
Tk <- function(n, k){
  T <- matrix(numeric(up(n, k)^2), ncol=up(n, k))
  T[up(0, k),up(0, k)] <- 1
  for (i in 1:(2*n)){
    for (j in max(0, i-n):min(i, n)){
      T[up(i-j, k), up(j, k)] <- sum(T[up(j, k), up(i-j-k, k):up(i-j-1, k)])
      }
    }
  T[up(1, k):up(n, k), up(1, k):up(n, k)]
  }
```

As a check, when $k=2$ or $3$ we get for the initial terms

```
Tab2 <- Tk(10, 2)
2 * Tab2[cbind(1:10, 1:10)]
#     2    6   14   34   84  208  518 1296 3254 8196
Tab3 <- Tk(10, 3)
2 * Tab3[cbind(1:10, 1:10)]
#      2     6    20    62   194   616  1972  6344 20498 66486
```

which are the initial terms of [OEIS A177790](https://oeis.org/A177790) and of [OEIS A177792](https://oeis.org/A177792), while if we try $k\ge n$ then $k$ is not a constraint and we expect the answer to be the relevant binomial coefficient ${2n \choose n}$, and it is.  For example with $n=50$ and $k=123$:

```
Tab123 <- Tk(50, 123)
2 * Tab123[50, 50]
# 1.008913e+29
choose(100, 50)
# 1.008913e+29
```

Those checks make me trust the code. We can now answer the the particular example given:

```
Tab6 <- Tk(50, 6)
2 * Tab6[cbind(50, 50)]
# 5.268638e+28
```

which is just over half the number for $n=50$ without the $k=6$ constraint.

It would not surprise me if the asymptotic approximation when $k=6$ was something not too far away from about $0.679 \frac{3.9346^n}{\sqrt{n}}$; compare this to the unconstrained asymptotic approximation which is about $0.564\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.